# Inverse dynamics control: Proof of asymptotic stability of error system

Tags: control-theory, linear-control, lyapunov-functions, robotics

The inverse dynamics control in robotic applications yields the error system
\begin{equation} \ddot{\mathbf{e}} + \mathbf{K}_1 \dot{\mathbf{e}} + \mathbf{K}_0 {\mathbf{e}} = \mathbf{0} \end{equation}
or rewritten as ODE-system
$$ \frac{d}{dt} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{e} \\
\dot{\mathbf{e}}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I}\\
-\mathbf{K}_0 & -\mathbf{K}_1
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\mathbf{A}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{e} \\
\dot{\mathbf{e}}
\end{bmatrix} \text{ .}
$$
To prove asymptotic stability of the error system, A has to be a Hurwitz-Matrix.

Literature says that it is sufficient for $\mathbf{K}_0$ and $\mathbf{K}_1$ to be positive definite to guarantee asymptotic stability of the error system.

During the proof the assumption of $\mathbf{K}_0 = diag\{k_{0,1}, \dots, k_{0,n} \}$ and $\mathbf{K}_1 = diag\{k_{1,1}, \dots, k_{1,n} \}$ was made. This in return yields a decoupled system
$$
\frac{d}{dt} 
\begin{bmatrix}
{e_j} \\
\dot{{e}}_j
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
{0} & 1\\
-{k}_{0,j} & -{k}_{1,j}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\mathbf{A}_j}
\begin{bmatrix}
{e}_j \\
\dot{{e}_j}
\end{bmatrix} \text{ .}
$$
for $j=1, \dots, n$ with the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{A}_j$
$$ p_j(s) = s^2 + k_{1,j} s + k_{0,j} $$ which is a Hurwitz polynomial for $k_{1,j} > 0$ and $k_{0,j} > 0$, hence guarantees the asymptotic stability of the decoupled system.

$\textbf{BUT}$ I have not found a proof which relies only on the assumption of $\mathbf{K}_0$ and $\mathbf{K}_1$ to be positive definite.

I tried solving the Lyapunov equation
$$ 
\mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{P} + \mathbf{P} \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{0}
$$
with the positive definite matrices $\mathbf{P}$ respectively $\mathbf{Q}$ without much luck.

How can I proof asymptotic stability of the above-mentioned error system with only the assumption of $\mathbf{K}_0$ and $\mathbf{K}_1$ to be positive definite?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A related post lead me to the answer: [Help! Lyapunov proof for calculated torque control with friction term for robot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713488/help-lyapunov-proof-for-calculated-torque-control-with-friction-term-for-robot?rq=1)

The Lyapunov function
$$ 
V(\mathbf{e}, \dot{\mathbf{e}}) = \frac{1}{2} \dot{\mathbf{e}}^{T} \dot{\mathbf{e}} + \frac{1}{2} {\mathbf{e}}^{T} \mathbf{K}_0{\mathbf{e}} 
$$
yields $V(\mathbf{e}, \dot{\mathbf{e}}) > 0$ in case $\mathbf{K}_0$ is positive definite and
\begin{align}
\dot{V}(\mathbf{e}, \dot{\mathbf{e}}) &= \dot{\mathbf{e}}^{T} \ddot{\mathbf{e}} + \dot{\mathbf{e}}^{T} \mathbf{K}_0 \mathbf{e} \\
 &= - \dot{\mathbf{e}}^{T} \mathbf{K}_1 \dot{\mathbf{e}}
\end{align}
yields $\dot{V}(\mathbf{e}, \dot{\mathbf{e}}) \leq 0 $ in case $\mathbf{K}_1$ is positive definite.

According to LaSalle's invariance principle the error system is asymptotic stable as the largest invariant set $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \left\{\mathbf{e}, \dot{\mathbf{e}} \in \mathbb{R}^n ~|~ \dot{V}(\mathbf{e}, \dot{\mathbf{e}}) = \mathbf{0}\right\}$ is the origin itself: $\mathcal{M} = \{\mathbf{0}\} $.

Comment: I think $\dot{V} \leq 0$ only because you have $\mathbf{e}$ *and* $\dot{\mathbf{e}}$ as states so $V$ and $\dot{V}$ are functions of $\mathbf{e}$ and $\dot{\mathbf{e}}$. So $\dot{V}(\mathbf{e}, \dot{\mathbf{e}})$ should be negative semi definite.

Comment: @SampleTime but in this case one can apply LaSalle to finish the proof.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen True. Alternatively there should exist a different $V$ such that $\dot{V}$ is actually negative definite. For scalar error $e$ the following should work: $V(e, \dot{e}) = \frac{1}{2}(k_0^2 + k_0 + k_1^2) e^2 + k_1 e \dot{e} + \frac{1}{2}(k_0 + 1) \dot{e}^2$ which leads to $\dot{V}(e, \dot{e}) = -k_0 k_1 (e^2 + \dot{e}^2)$ which is negative definite. This should probably also work if $\mathbb{e}$ is not a scalar (though I didn't check that).

Comment: Thanks, I finished the proof with the invariance principle.